# JSON escape double quotes

Tags: python, json, regex, escaping

I know this title seems rather popular on here, but a quick browse through them usually involves situations where the asker has one isolated section of JSON.

There are situations where `"` is used to signify inches, or it wraps a phrase to signify a nickname of some sort, either way it appears in the value string  of a JS object which is already wrapped in double quotes.

Here is an example of the JS object string I am having trouble with (I have working regex to double quote the keys and remove extra whitespace, but this is the scraped string in all of its glory):

```
'{\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"16241885":{title: "Nosefrida Fridababy Windi Gas &amp; Colic Relief", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
\n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t, \n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"8650356":{title: "Babyganics Face- Hand &amp; Baby Wipes- Fragrance Free- 100 Count", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
    \n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t, \n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"16249889":{title: "Nosefrida Nasal Aspirator Replacement Filters", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
    \n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t, \n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"8650355":{title: "Babyganics Face- Hand &amp; Baby Wipes- Fragrance Free- 40 Count", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
    \n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t, \n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"15490928":{title: "BabyGanics Newborn Ultra Absorbent Jumbo Size Diapers - 36 Count", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
    \n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t, \n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"14712536":{title: "Marvel Superhero Bandages", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
    \n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t, \n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"16263505":{title: "Nosefrida "The Snotsucker" Nasal Aspirator", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
    \n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t, \n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t \n\n\n\n 
"14848093":{title: "Zarbee\'s Children\'s Cough Syrup - Grape", isIneligible: false, isDiscontinued: false, isLowInventory: false, isAllowed: true}
    \n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t \n\n\t\t\n\t}'
```

I have tried, `json.dumps` on the string first but that just double escapes and needs a double `json.loads` which brings me back to square one. I have tried regex like this:

```
double_quotes_in_json = re.compile(r'(?<=:)(\s*"[^"]*)(")([^"]*)(")?(?=[^"]*",|"\s*\})')


def escape_double_quotes(jsn_string, pattern=double_quotes_in_json):
    for match in pattern.finditer(jsn_string):
        # current pattern only matches 1 instance of either one double quote in JSON value string
        # (presumably signifying inches) or 1 instance of phrase wrapped in double quotes
        # for something like nicknames
        # matches will have either 3 or 4 groups, representing one of the 2 match types described above
        groups_matched = len(match.groups())
        entire_match = match.group()
        if groups_matched == 3:
            # we only matched one double quote
            subbed_match = pattern.sub('$1\\$2$3', entire_match)
            jsn_string = re.sub(entire_match, subbed_match, jsn_string)
        elif groups_matched == 4:
            # we matched a phrase wrapped in double quotes
            subbed_match = pattern.sub('$1\\$2$3\\$4', entire_match)
            jsn_string = re.sub(entire_match, subbed_match, jsn_string)
    return jsn_string
```

And while this seems the most promising, it seems to re-insert the double quotes without the escape chars I have in the sub, while also not subbing back in the first group.(I have tried with and without a raw string in the sub function `r`) So for the above problem section (below is a substring):

```
 "16263505":{title: "Nosefrida "The Snotsucker" Nasal Aspirator"
```

The pattern doesn't sub group 1 back in and for some reason subs in a single quote (below is a substring of the failed regex processing):

```
"16263505":{title: "The Snotsucker"' Nasal Aspirator"
```

Either way `json.loads` complains about the unescaped `"`.

Edit 1:
My regex can pull out the unescaped quotes but subbing it back in isn't behaving as expected, I am probably doing something stupid here and could use a fresh set of eyes.

example output of my function with print statements:

```
low_inventory = response.xpath(
                '//script[contains(., "islistEligibility") or contains(., "ishlistEligibility")]/text()'
                ).re_first(r'(?s)(?<=registryWislistEligibilityMap)(?:\s*=\s*)(\{.+\})')

In [453]: for m in double_quotes_in_json.finditer(low_inventory):
     ...:     groups_matched = len(m.groups())
     ...:     print('groups: ', m.groups())
     ...:     entire_match = m.group()
     ...:     print('entire match: ', m.group())
     ...:     if groups_matched == 3:
     ...:             # we only matched a single double quote
     ...:             subbed_match = double_quotes_in_json.sub(r'$1\\$2$3', entire_match)
     ...:             print('subbed3: ', subbed_match)
     ...:             jsn_string = re.sub(entire_match, subbed_match, jsn_string)
     ...:     elif groups_matched == 4:
     ...:             subbed_match = double_quotes_in_json.sub(r'$1\\$2$3\\\$4', entire_match)
     ...:             print('subbed4: ', subbed_match)
     ...:             jsn_string = re.sub(entire_match, subbed_match, jsn_string)
     ...: print(jsn_string)
     ...: 
groups:  (' "Nosefrida ', '"', 'The Snotsucker', '"')
entire match:   "Nosefrida "The Snotsucker"
subbed4:   "Nosefrida "The Snotsucker"
{  "16241885":{"title": "Nosefrida Fridababy Windi Gas &amp; Colic Relief", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true},   "8650356":{"title": "Babyganics Face- Hand &amp; Baby Wipes- Fragrance Free- 100 Count", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true},   "16249889":{"title": "Nosefrida Nasal Aspirator Replacement Filters", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true},   "8650355":{"title": "Babyganics Face- Hand &amp; Baby Wipes- Fragrance Free- 40 Count", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true},   "15490928":{"title": "BabyGanics Newborn Ultra Absorbent Jumbo Size Diapers - 36 Count", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true},   "14712536":{"title": "Marvel Superhero Bandages", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true},   "16263505":{"title": "The Snotsucker"' Nasal Aspirator", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true},   "14848093":{"title": "Zarbee's Children's Cough Syrup - Grape", "isIneligible": false, "isDiscontinued": false, "isLowInventory": false, "isAllowed": true} }
```

Comment: That is neither valid JSON nor Javascript. It's invalid in any language I can think of. You're trying to parse garbage. Where does this garbage come from? Can it be fixed at the source?

Comment: @deceze It is scraped from a script tag. What would make it invalid JS?

Comment: That script should be crashing with syntax errors when anyone attempts to execute it. Is this surely the raw data? Any chance some ``\`` are being stripped out during the scraping process?

Comment: Is the data you presented before or after you start manipulating it with the regex you discuss?

Comment: @deceze regex is grabbing the entire object. My processing regex (quote keys, strip whitespace then json.loads) works for the majority of the data I have gathered, only chokes on these examples with unescaped double quotes

Comment: @jwpfox the example data was prior to any manipulation

Comment: If you know the data has a defined structure, you should parse it accordingly, e.g. `title: "(.+?)" isIneligible: …`. The string delimiters are, again, garbage and can obviously not be relied upon for parsing. If there's no such thing you can rely upon… well, as far as any sane parser is concerned, there is no right answer for this string.

Comment: @deceze my issue seems to be with attempting to escape the quotes once my regex has found it. Perhaps you can make some suggestions with regards to how my function tries to sub the escapes? If you just cut and paste my code and the example you will see the regex finds the offending unescaped quote but has issues subbing in the escaped quotes.

Comment: Since the quotes are a jumbled mess, there's no sane rule you can follow to fix them. Again, treating the text as opaque blob without specific format and trying to regex the necessary information out of it is probably the sanest approach here.

Comment: @deceze pulling it out isn't the issue, its subbing it back in. I will add an edit...

Comment: @deceze edits should clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, using pythons builtin replace function achieved the desired result whereas re.sub did not properly escape the double quotes. (this was with using groups references in a raw string with a single escape or a regular string with double escapes). Either way, here is the working function. If someone has some insight as to why using replace works over re.sub I would be very interested into why this is.

(old code commented out)

```
double_quotes_in_json = re.compile(r'(?<=:)(\s*")([^"]*)(")([^"]*)(")?(?=[^"]*",|"\s*\})')


def escape_double_quotes(jsn_string, pattern=double_quotes_in_json):
    for match in pattern.finditer(jsn_string):
        # current pattern only matches 1 instance of either one double quote in JSON value string
        # (presumably signifying inches) or 1 instance of phrase wrapped in double quotes
        # for something like nicknames
        # matches will have either 3 or 4 groups, representing one of the 2 match types described above
        num_groups_matched = len(match.groups())
        groups = match.groups()
        entire_match = match.group()
        print('groups: ', match.groups())
        print('entire: ', entire_match)
        if num_groups_matched == 4:
            # we only matched one double quote
            # subbed_match = pattern.sub('$1$2\\$3$4', entire_match)
            # jsn_string = re.sub(entire_match, subbed_match, jsn_string)
            target = ''.join(groups[1:4])
            replaced = target.replace('"', '\\"')
            print(replaced)
            jsn_string = jsn_string.replace(target, replaced)
        elif num_groups_matched == 5:
            # we matched a phrase wrapped in double quotes
            # subbed_match = pattern.sub('$1$2\\$3$4\\$5', entire_match)
            # jsn_string = re.sub(entire_match, subbed_match, jsn_string)
            target = ''.join(groups[1:])
            replaced = target.replace('"', '\\"')
            print(replaced)
            jsn_string = jsn_string.replace(target, replaced)
    return jsn_string
```

Edit #1 (AKA: after some sleep approach):

```
double_quotes_in_title_attr = re.compile(
    r'(?<="title":)(?:\s*")(?P<value>.+?)(?=",\s*"\w+":|"\s*\})'
)


def escape_double_quotes_in_title(jsn_string, pattern=double_quotes_in_title_attr):
    for match in pattern.finditer(jsn_string):
        target = match.group('value')
        replaced = target.replace('"', '\\"')
        jsn_string = jsn_string.replace(target, replaced)
    return jsn_string

# use this first to properly quote keys so the above pattern will match
unquoted_key_pattern = re.compile(r'(?!")(\'?(?P<key>\w+)\'?)(?=:\s*(?:"|false|true|\d|\[|\{))')

def fix_json_keys(jsn, pattern=unquoted_key_pattern):
    return pattern.sub(r'"\g<key>"', jsn)
```

Thanks for the help @deceze.